# Updating database in JSP

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

I coded this Java code for my JSP page to update current login details of a user. Code is not showing any errors or exceptions but not updates the MySql database.

Help me to to implement this functionality;

My code:

```
<%
//variable declaration for encrypt and decrypt
byte [] input ;
byte [] keyBytes = "12345678".getBytes();
byte [] ivBytes ="input123".getBytes();

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes,"DES");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
Cipher cipher;
byte[] cipherText;
int ctLength=0;

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

if(request.getParameter("submit")!=null){
    String cuser=request.getParameter("currentusername"); 
    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
    String cpwd = request.getParameter("confirmpassword");

    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
      input = pwd.getBytes();
      key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DES");
      ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CTR/NoPadding","BC");

      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
      cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];

      ctLength+=cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);

      ctLength+= cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
      String enpwd = new String(cipherText);


     String sql2 = "update webadmin set username=? ,password=? where username='"+cuser+"' ";

     if((cuser!=null &&cuser.length()>0) 
        && (user!=null &&user.length()>0)  
        && (pwd!=null && pwd.length()>0)
        && cpwd!=null && cpwd.length()>0) {

         if((pwd.equals(cpwd))){
           pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
           pst.setString(1, user);
           pst.setString(2, enpwd);

            pst.executeUpdate();
%>
 <script language="JavaScript">
     alert("Sucessfully Updated");
 </script>
 <%
         }else{
             %>
           <script language="JavaScript">
            alert("Passwords are not matching try again");
            </script>
           <%

     }
    }
  }
}

%>
```

Note: I implement to encrypt the password and store that encrypted password to the database.

HTML form;

```
<form id="login-form"  action="adminpg-mysettings.jsp" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="currentusername" id="currentusername" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Username" value="" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="New Username" value="" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm New Password" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Save">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: print out the query and try it on a ad console. maybe you get not expected data.

Comment: Check in debug for conditions, be sure that every condition is satisfied to make the update. Else, be sure what cuser exists in db, otherwise the sql condition will not match.

Comment: just why in jsp? why connection username password is also in jsp?

Comment: Is there any exception ?  Did you try to fire the same Query in Database console as well ? Does it work ?

Comment: Just as a note for later: it's a very bad idea to combine JSP and Java code. That was what they did in the late 90's / early 00's, because they didn't know better.

Answer (score 0):

First of, like everyone will tell you, it is a very bad idea to put Java in JSP. The correct way of operating is with a Servlet and requests stored in session. It will prevent malicious [sql injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Second of, your security constraints should be handled in the `web.xml` and `Servlet`, which is best for back-end maintenance. Following good programming practice will prevent you from going crazy over bugging logs.

I can help you implement what you are trying to do with a Servlet, but before I do, I need to know the following:

- The obvious: Do you have a Servlet?
- Do you use JDBC/JNDI connectivity?
- Do you have entity and session classes for user?
- Which IDE/framework do you use to develop your app?
- What server are you deploying to?

It is the most effective way of accomplishing what you want. Please provide with the answers and I will update my answer with some code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class UpdateController extends HttpServlet {
    
        
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    
        }
    
        
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            request.setAttribute("id", new StudentDAO().getStudent(id));
            request.getRequestDispatcher("update.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            Date dob = Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("dob")); // yyyy-mm-dd
            String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
            Student s = new Student();
            s.setId(id);
            s.setName(name);
            s.setGender(gender);
            s.setDob(dob);
            StudentDAO db = new StudentDAO();
            db.update(s);
            response.sendRedirect("list");
            request.setAttribute("students", new StudentDAO().getAll());
    //        request.getRequestDispatcher("list.jsp").forward(request, response);
    
        }
     public void update(Student s) {
            try {
                String sql = "UPDATE [dbo].[Student]\n"
                        + "   SET [name] = ?\n"
                        + "      ,[gender] = ?\n"
                        + "      ,[dob] = ?\n"
                        + " WHERE id = ?";
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, s.getName());
                ps.setString(2, s.getGender());
                ps.setDate(3, s.getDob());
                ps.setInt(4, s.getId());
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(StudentDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Update</title>
        <%  String id = request.getParameter("id");%>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="update" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID: <input type="text" name="id" 
                                   value="<%=id%>" readonly></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/> Male
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> Female </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dob: <input type="date" name="dob" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </form>
    </body>
```